# windows 7 64 bit visual studio 2008 libtiff build nmake error

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I am trying to build tiff 4.0.2 on my Windows 7 x64 system with Visual Studio 2008, but it was showing errors:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2347) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'QINT'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2362) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2397) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'JOYCAPS'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2397) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2398) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PJOYCAPS'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2398) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2399) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'NPJOYCAPS'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2399) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2400) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPJOYCAPS'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2400) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2534) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'pjc'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2534) : error C2081: 'LPJOYCAPSA' : name in formal parameter list illegal
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2534) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'pjc'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2534) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2534) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(2534) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

NMAKE: fatal error u1077: "c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\bin\cl.exe": return code '0x2'
```

This is what I was doing:

1. Extracted tiff 4.0.2
2. In VS 2008 x64 Win 7 command prompt setting the environment for x86 by running `vcvars32.bat`
3. Changing the path to tiff 4.0.2/libtiff folder
4. Running `nmake /f makefile.vc` to create a static library of libtiff

Following these steps in Windows XP generates the .lib file but in Windows 7 it fails.

This is the first time I'm making any .lib files.

Comment: You dump an error message mess (I have edited if so it's at least readable) and you don't show the code the errors are about. That won't get you much help. Please edit your code into the question. Give it a 4-space indent so it formats as a code block.

Comment: i m explaining what i m doing
1. extracted tiff 4.0.2
2. in vs 2008 x64 win 64 command prompt setting the environment for x86 by running vcvars32.bat
3.changing the path to tiff4.0.2/libtiff folder
4. Running nmake /f makefile.vc to create a static library of libtiff
then these errors comes into picture. I dnt know what goes wrong ...following these steps in windows XP generates the .lib file but in windows 7 it fails

This is the first time i m making any .lib so i m just a beginner